# Trying to have no images loaded when website initially starts

Tags: php, html, image, radio-button

I have a div in which the image is updated upon selecting the corresponding radio box and pressing a submit button:

```
<form action="test1.php" method="POST">
    <b>SPE</b> <input type="radio" name="spType" value="SPE">
    <b>SPI</b> <input type="radio" name="spType" value="SPI">       
    <input type="submit" name = "go">   
    </form>
```

The post method then checks for what was selected and stores the name within a PHP variable called $spType, this is then put in an if statement:

```
<div id="mainImage">                
            <?php if($spType=="SPI") { ?>
             <div id="mainImageSPI">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SPIopen.css" /> 
            </div>
            <?php }elseif($spType=="SPE") { ?>
            <div id="mainImageSPE"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/SPEopen.css" />            
            </div>
            <?php }; ?>             
</div>
```

It is working as expected (once SPE or SPI selected and button pressed image updates) but when the website first loads up the image for SPE is automatically loaded, I would like for it to be a blank screen with no image once the website is initially loaded.

I tried to do this by creating an additional radio button called "BLANK" and setting this to checked but since it was inside the form it didn't work however, when this check box was selected the screen did go blank as expected.

Comment: Show us php code where you handle $_POST, in general you need `$spType` to be empty by default (if there is no value in $_POST)

Comment: i am assuming you have set the value for $spType as SPI as default somewhere causing the image to be loaded

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent ages trying to figure this one out but totally forgot that I preset it in the PHP file. Could you please answer the question so that I can pick you as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as requested in comment:

You need `$spType` to be empty by default (if `$_POST['spType']` is not set)